# VWD 2010 express asking for registration key

Tags: registration, vwdexpress

I downloaded Visula Studio 2010 express offline images which includes VWD,C#,VB express and installed but after 30 days it's asking me for registration key (need to register the product). Problem is I don't have internet connection and I don't see any other way of registering the product rather than doing it from my machine.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the links on the right side of [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/regins/), it will email you a registration key that you can use on the machine that doesn't have Internet access.

Comment: Am I a fool! Why didn't I noticed this while I was browsing through this MS site ... may be I was very much frustrated thinking that I may not be able to use the express stuff any more. Thanks a lot John.

Comment: No problem.  The way they hid it off to the side, I missed it at first too.